# NSwag default accept response to application/json

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, nswag

I'm using NSwag with an Asp.Net Core API. I would like to change the default accepted response from `application/octet-stream` to `application/json`.

[image]

I tried adding Response attribute to the API action and also the OpenApiMimeType but did not work. It is still set to `application/octet-stream`. How do I change this?

Update:
Here is one of the actions for the API.

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginDto dto, string returnUrl = null)
{
    //... omitted codes for brevity
    
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your web api's controller method? What the type of that parameter and returned type you have used?

Comment: I have created a test demo on my side according to your method, and it works well, It shows the result is application/json. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH1Zh.png). Could you please tell me your Nswag version?

Comment: @BrandoZhang 13.7.4.

Comment: @BrandoZhang if it helps, I'm using this template: https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture

Answer (score 1):

Using the Produce attribute (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesattribute) should help you achieve this.

```
[HttpPost("login")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginDto dto, string returnUrl = null)
{
    //... omitted codes for brevity
    
    return Ok();
}
```

In your swagger.json it should produce something like this: Swagger.json - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjhw2.png)

The other reason is because you are using `Task<ActionResult>` so your swagger.json isn't producing a content type due to this reason.

```
[HttpPost("login")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<ActionResult<return something>> Login(LoginDto dto, string returnUrl = null)
{
    //... omitted codes for brevity
    
    return Ok(return something);
}
```

Comment: I already use the Produce on your first sample, same result. It does not change the response type. Already figure out how to make this as `application/json`. What I did is to return a proper type something like `Task<ActionResult<string>>`.